I stumbled upon an unexpected behaviour in C# - Can an array change its size implicitly?
I'm new to programming and just started C#, so just basic exercises. I was trying to just populate an array with random values and getting the biggest number and how many times it repeated.
I'm running .NET 8.0, C# 12.
using static System.Random;

uint[] numberList = new uint[8];
WriteLine(numberList.Length);
/*
for (uint i = 0; i < numberList.Length;i++) {
numberList[i] = (uint)new Random().Next(0,9);
}
*/
numberList = [1,1,1,2,3,8,8,7,10,10,11];
WriteLine(numberList.Length);
uint[] biggerNum = [0,0];

for (uint i = 0; i < numberList.Length; i++){
    if (numberList[i] > biggerNum[0]) {
        biggerNum[0] = numberList[i];
    }
    WriteLine("Value of i: " + i);
    WriteLine("Value in the array: " + numberList[i]);
}

for (uint i = 0; i < numberList.Length; i++) {
    if (numberList[i] == biggerNum[0]) biggerNum[1]++;
}

WriteLine(format:"The number: {0} \nRepeated: {1} times.",
            arg0:biggerNum[0],
            arg1:biggerNum[1]);

While fiddling with it, I declared an array of size 10. But after I populated it with 11 values, it just got resized.
I was expecting to get a compile error, but it just worked. Then I thought "maybe the compiler just recognized that I used 11 values and resized it at compilation?"
But no, running the code I could see that it was in fact declared with size 10 and after
numberList = [1,1,1,2,3,8,8,7,10,10,11];

it just got resized to 11. I tried with multiple values, starting it with 8, 5 and then assigning more.
Is there something I'm missing? I tried using Gemini to find out if it should resize, but it just kept saying that changing an array size isn't possible, which is what I was expecting. Didn't find this specifically in the documentation.
I know I should declare like uint[] numberList = [1,1,1,2,3,8,8,7,10,10,11]; but this is behaving like I'm shadowing the array even though I'm just assigning a value (in a stupid way I know).

It didn’t get resized – you replaced it with a reference to an entirely new array.

And Gemini is wrong in any case if it said that.

Related: Can you define an array with a pre-specified size in C#?

The array was not resized.
You declared an array called numberList. Arrays are reference types, and you made it reference an array with 8 elements. You then assigned an array with more elements, so that numberList now references the larger array.
But the original array was left unchanged. And since nothing references it anymore, it can now be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

new uint[8];

This creates a new array with 8 elements.
uint[] numberList = // ...

This creates a reference to array, named numberList, and assigns an object to it, in this case the 8-element array.
[1,1,1,2,3,8,8,7,10,10,11];

This creates a different array with 11 elements.
numberList = // ...

This makes numberList reference the new array (with 11 elements). The 8-element array is no longer referenced.

oh that makes sense, i thought i was just like initializing/populating the array. Seeing this as a reference makes it clear. In this case, what happens with the first array? goes to Garbage collection? should i take this as a concern regarding performance?

@giurnoB The first array would be free to be garbage-collected now, yes. Your example program doesn't make much sense as-is, because it is printing the size of the first array, then there's the commented-out part filling that array, and then you're switching to a different array. Of course it would give better performance if you just dropped the first lines (prior to assigning the second array), but I'd assume you want an array with random numbers eventually, so your final code would look different anyway. (t.b.c.)

Unfortunately, and somewhat akin to Java, in an attempt to make C# "better" than C++ they dropped the explicitness of what's an object and what's a reference to an object. Nullable references are an attempt to rectify that problem, but they are optional, there's lots of legacy code not making use of them, and there are exceptions to them, so all in all things are much more confusing in this regard in C# instead of "better". The bottom line rule of thumb is, a reference should only be declared where it can be initialized.
